# Buy 10 of X/Y/Z and get 1 of X/Y/Z free

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to set this price rule. Is it possible?

```
Example: 2X + 9Y = 1X or 1Y or 1Z free
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't came with better solution, then make 5 basically same rules.

There is differences only in "total quantity of items" more than 10,20,30,40,50 for each rule.

Everything else is just same even title of the rule, so when some buys 25 of them it show only one title of sale and sum of sale.

It's not pretty solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
If total quantity  equals or greater than  10  for a subselection of items in cart matching ANY  of these conditions:
    SKU  is  x 
    SKU  is  y 
    SKU  is  z
```

Actions: Amount of $ for x,y,z or if different prices set up rules in here also. You may need 3 different rules for each product you intend to give away.

Comment: That's smart, thank you. But how about if I want to set for 10+1 and for more thirsty buyers 20+2, 30+3..?